# show multiple selected span values in jquery using comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've posted my full code on jsfiddle. I'm trying to show the user selected seats here. If user selected 2 from BS the result should be BS-2. Again if user selected 4 from FC the result should be added with the old one like BS-2, FC-4.

But, I've tried something here. its show the value of span element but if i selected the another one it replaces the previous one. How to add a comma and show the multiple selected span values in jquery?

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U5DPQ/)

**jQuery**

```
$(".text").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var data = $(this).text();
    $('.returndata').text(data);
})
```

Comment: your problem is , it just show one result ?

Comment: @code360 : yes. now its solved..

Comment: you welcome without any reasons people give downvoted .it's not good :( i am feel sorry for that upvoted :) from  me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ferrakkem/U5DPQ/5/ i am also solved your problem

Comment: @code360 : thanks anyway. i got the solution from arun p johnny...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $texts = $(".text").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var selected = $texts.filter('.selected').map(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text())
    }).get()
    $('.returndata').text(selected.join());
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hTqWB/)

Comment: It doesn't generate expected result

Comment: its working. but how to add the specific text BS,FC,SC before the result. if i have a one id i will add like this `text('BS ' +data);` i have multiple ids. how to do that?

Comment: if you select 2 from BS another from FC how should it display

Comment: @ArunPJohny : output should be BS-2, FC-4, SC-3